# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

[javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to website.com/2a06:98c1:3120::3 (port 443) after 60000ms]

I tried alot of solutions but it didnt work with me .

anyone can help please ..

NOTE : My SSL Certificate from cloudflare ..

And this problem working with old devices lollipop and below.

```
def retrofit2_v = '2.9.0'
```

my code : ->

```
import okhttp3.*
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.security.KeyStore
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.Collections
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager


class RetrofitInstance {
    companion object {
//        val interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
//            this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
//        }
//        val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
//            this.addInterceptor(interceptor)
//        }.build()

        fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApIConstant.BASE_URL)
                .client(getHeader()!!)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        fun getRetrofitInstanceWeather(): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/")
                .client(getHeader())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }
}

fun getHeader(): OkHttpClient? {
    val spec: ConnectionSpec = ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
        .cipherSuites(
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        )
        .build()
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    val trustManagerFactory =
        TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    trustManagerFactory.init(null as KeyStore?)
    val trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.trustManagers
    check(!(trustManagers.size != 1 || trustManagers[0] !is X509TrustManager)) {
        "Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(
            trustManagers
        )
    }
    val trustManager = trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sslContext.init(null, arrayOf<TrustManager>(trustManager), null)
    val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
    httpClient.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
    /***********************/

    val interceptorJ = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptorJ)
    httpClient.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
//    httpClient.addInterceptor(ChuckerInterceptor(MyApplication.application))
    httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    httpClient.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val original: Request = chain.request()
            val builder: Request.Builder = original.newBuilder()
            builder.method(original.method, original.body)
            builder.header("Accept", "application/json")

//            builder.header("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
//                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

            return chain.proceed(builder.build())
        }
    })

    /*if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        httpClient.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    }*/
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS)
    val client: OkHttpClient = httpClient.build()

    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    return client
}

interface GenricApiService {


    @DELETE
    fun GenricDELETE(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String?,
        @Url url: String?,
        @QueryMap parameters: Map<String, String>
    ): Call<ResponseBody>

    @GET
    fun GenricGET(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String?,
        @Url url: String?,
        @QueryMap parameters: Map<String, String>
    ): Call<ResponseBody>


    @GET
    fun GenricGetWeather(
        @Url url: String?,
    ): Call<ResponseBody>

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST
    fun GenricPOST(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String?,
        @Url url: String?,
        @FieldMap parameters: Map<String, String>
    ): Call<ResponseBody>


//    @POST
//    fun POST_RAW(@Url url: String?, @Body body: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody?>?


    @POST()
    fun POST_Multipart(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String?,
        @Url url: String?,
        @Body body: RequestBody?
    ): Call<ResponseBody?>?
    @POST()
    fun saveDataAsJson(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String?,
        @Url url: String?,
        @Body row: Any
    ): Call<ResponseBody>



}


// aplication class
override fun onCreate() {
        setLocaleEn(this)
      

        super.onCreate()

        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(applicationContext)
            val sslContext: SSLContext
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
            sslContext.init(null, null, null)
            sslContext.createSSLEngine()
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: KeyManagementException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        SSLCertificateHandler().nuke()
    }
```